# Feature 'xxx' depends on 'yyy' which is not an optional dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I got this error:

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `...\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  Feature `client` depends on `rusttls` which is not an optional dependency.
Consider adding `optional = true` to the dependency
```

It goes away if I add `optional = true`, but I don't want rusttls to be optional for security reasons.

What's the exact cause of this error and possible solutions other than making it optional?

My Cargo.toml has this:

```
[features]

default = ["client", "server"]

client = ["serde_json",  "serde-xml-rs", "serde_ignored", "hyper", "hyper-tls", "rusttls", "tokio-core", "url", "uuid", "multipart"]

server = ["serde_json", "serde-xml-rs", "serde_ignored", "hyper", "hyper-tls", "rusttls", "tokio-core", "tokio-proto", "tokio-tls", "regex", "percent-encoding", "url", "uuid", "multipart"]
```

From what I read in the Rust book, doing this should mean that by default the client and server have these dependencies, right?

Comment: Just reread https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section  and I get what the issue is. Because I used a tool to automatically generate this I didn't know why this was failing, features only for optional compilation so yes @Shepmaster, there's no need to add compulsory crates under [features] . Sorry for that, I was pretty sure that the issue was to do with [features] and that's why I only posted about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only include a dependency in a feature list if the dependency is optional. If the dependency is not optional, solely include it in the `[dependencies]` section.